# Loop won't concatenate a string more than once

Tags: vb.net, loops, while-loop

I'm currently doing a soundex system for homework. For the assignment, I need to replace certain letters with certain numbers. For the assignment, I'm using a do loop. The problem is that only one letter in the string is replaced with a number, while the rest of the letters besides the first one are deleted. For example, Robert is supposed to come out as "R163," but it instead comes out as "R300". I was wondering what I'm doing wrong. My code is:

```
Private Sub btnCompute_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCompute.Click
    Dim word As String = txtInput.Text
    Dim first As String = txtInput.Text.Substring(0, 1)
    Dim rest As String = txtInput.Text.Substring(1, word.Length - 1)
    Dim test As String = ""
    Dim combine As String = ""

    Dim i As Integer = 0
    Do
        Select Case rest.Substring(i)
            Case "a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "h", "y", "w"
                test &= ""

            Case "b", "f", "p", "v"
                test &= "1"

            Case "c", "g", "j", "k", "q", "s", "x", "z"
                test &= "2"

            Case "d", "t"
                test &= "3"

            Case "l"
                test &= "4"

            Case "m", "n"
                test &= "5"

            Case "r"
                test &= "6"
        End Select
        i += 1
    Loop Until i > rest.Length

    combine = first & test

    If combine.Length < 4 Then
        Do While combine.Length < 4
            combine &= "0"
        Loop

    ElseIf combine.Length > 4 Then
        combine = combine.Substring(4)
    End If

    txtSound.Text = combine
End Sub
```

Comment: Use the most appropriate loop for the circumstances.  In this case, that would be a `For Each` or maybe a `For` loop.  You should also read the documentation fort that `Substring` method you're calling. It doesn't do what you think it does.  If you just want one character then index the `String` directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying to keep things as similar to your example... This should work.

```
    Dim word As String = txtInput.Text
    Dim test As String = String.Empty
    Dim combine As String = String.Empty

    For i As Integer = 1 To word.Length - 1
        Select Case word.Substring(i, 1)
            Case "a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "h", "y", "w"
                test &= ""

            Case "b", "f", "p", "v"
                test &= "1"

            Case "c", "g", "j", "k", "q", "s", "x", "z"
                test &= "2"

            Case "d", "t"
                test &= "3"

            Case "l"
                test &= "4"

            Case "m", "n"
                test &= "5"

            Case "r"
                test &= "6"
        End Select
    Next

    combine = (word.Substring(0, 1) & test).PadRight(4, "0")
    txtSound.Text = combine
```